# Languages with words for human relationships based on the marital status of the persons related?

Tags: list-of-languages, sociolinguistics

What languages, if any, have generic words for describing the following human relationships:

```
   Relation of: Unmarried man   Married man  Unmarried woman    Married woman
To:
Unmarried man   ?               ?            ?                  ?
Married man     ?               ?            ?                  ?
Unmarried woman ?               ?            ?                  ?
Married woman   ?               ?            ?                  ?
```

Although, e.g.,

- "married woman → married man" could be "wife" or "adulteress"
- "unmarried woman → unmarried man" could be "girlfriend" or "fiancée"
- "married man → married woman" could be "husband" or "adulterer"
- etc.

or many other things in particular cases, I'm looking for languages with generic words describing these relationships based on the marital status of the persons related.

Comment: Are you looking for words describing relationships arising out of marriage (or the absence of marriage) only. Reason I ask is there could be family relationship words between two individuals where the marital status of the individuals comes into play while describing the relationship. For eg: In Tamil, two married men become சகலை when they each become husbands of sisters. Two women married to brothers become ஓரகத்தி.

Comment: @vvgiri "_family relationship words between two individuals where the marital status of the individuals comes into play_" isn't general enough for what I'm looking for, but is is interesting that Tamil makes such distinctions.